# Borel-Cantelli Lemma and Derandomization

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, derandomization, pr.probability, measure-theory

I was reading a paper titled [Random Oracles with(out) Programmability](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~teshrim/npro.pdf). The last paragraph of section 2.3 reads:

> *[Using our novel approach]* there is no
>   need to apply well-known classical asymptotic (and uniform) **derandomization**
>   techniques based on the **Borel-Cantelli lemma**. To the best of our knowledge,
>   this approach is novel to this paper.

I took a look at Wikipedia's entry for [Borel–Cantelli lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma), and almost grasped the idea. However, I couldn't still figure out how it relates to derandomization. In addition, I don't understand the meaning of "asymptotic" and "uniform" in the aforementioned paragraph.

PS: Googling for **Borel-Cantelli** and **derandomization** will show several interesting results, but I don't have enough background to understand them well.

Comment: Tiny commment: The usage of Borel-Cantelli lemma in complexity theory seems to be related to the *resource-bounded measure theory* introduced by [Lutz](http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~lutz/=PAPERS/aehnc.ps), and some follow-ups [here](http://reference.kfupm.edu.sa/content/i/m/improved_resource_bounded_borel_cantelli_1873529.pdf), [here](http://reference.kfupm.edu.sa/content/m/e/measure_on_small_complexity_classes__wit_171201.pdf) and [here](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~regan/papers/pdf/RSC95.pdf). I'm also interested in this question, hope that we'll have some nice answers!

Comment: @Hsien-Chih: Thanks. I also saw Lutz's works, but they were too complicated for me :( I hope someone describes it in "layman's terms" ;)

Comment: I guess that if your random events are something like line of code executed at time step $t$ and you can apply Borel-Cantelli, then your program terminates always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think they mean derandomization in the traditional sense.  Try looking at the application of the BC lemma in this paper for an example of what they are talking about: http://www.cs.bu.edu/~reyzin/hash.html.

They say "asymptotic" because most BB separations apply to concepts like one-way functions, which are defined asymptotically.  Their result is instead a "concrete" bound that applies to all values of the security parameters, not just sufficiently large values.